# QT QDialog not hiding properly when show/hide called quickly

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qdialog

I have a QDialog on my main thread and I have some logic that happens on a separate thread. When the logic begins, a signal is emitted connected to show() on the dialog. When the logic ends, a signal is emitted that is connected to hide() on the dialog. When the logic actually does work, the dialog is show/hide properly. If the logic does "nothing" and the signals are just emitted sequentially, the dialog doesn't always show/hide properly.

My connections are made similar to this:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget* parent = 0) :
        Ui(new Ui::MainWindowUi),
        Transferer(new DataTransferer()),
        TransferProgress(this),
        TransferThread()
    {
        Ui->setupUi();
        connect(&Transferer, SIGNAL(Begin()), &TransferProgress, SLOT(show()));
        connect(&Transferer, SIGNAL(End()), &TransferProgress, SLOT(hide()));

        Transferer.moveToThread(&TransferThread);
        TransferThread.start();

        Transferer.DoStuff(true);
    }

    virtual ~MainWindow()
    {
        TransferThread.quit();
        TransferThread.wait(1000);            

        delete Ui;
        Ui = NULL;
    }

private:
    Ui::MainWindowUi* Ui;
    DataTransferer Transferer;
    TransferProgressDialog TransferProgress;
    QThread TransferThread;
}
```

The logic looks similar to this:

```
class DataTransferer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DataTransferer(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {}
    virtual ~DataTransferer() {}

    void DoStuff(bool dontDoStuff)
    {
        emit Start();
        if (!dontDoStuff)
        {
            QThread::sleep(1);
        }
        emit End();
    }
}
```

When the DataTransferer does stuff, everything works fine. When the dialog is shown and hidden in rapid succession, I get the ghost dialog approximately every other time I call DoStuff().

I used QThread::currentThreadId() and verified that the dialog and logic are running on separate threads.

Why would my dialog not hide properly in this case? Should I just force my logic to always run for at least a few hundred milliseconds (that solution is bad)? Is there a way I can have my dialog make sure it's fully loaded before trying to hide itself? Should I handle these signals/slots differently?

EDIT: I've currently resigned to just putting a QThread::sleep(1) after I emit the signal to show() the dialog. I don't like this solution, but nothing else has seemed to work. The sleep(1) allows the dialog to come all the way up before hiding it. I was also able to get this to work with QThread::msleep(10), but that still resulted in the ghost dialog about 1 in 6 tries.

I tried using a member QMutex in the dialog logic whenever I called either show() or hide(), but this didn't work.

I changed all cross-thread connections to use Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection and Qt::QueuedConnection and neither attempt was successful.

I tried moving the slot connections from the dialog to the object that sets up the connections and then calling the slots directly, but that didn't prove successful either.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, show dialog and when get some signals to close it, when time less than 20ms(which means quickly hide the dialog), it will left a ghost dialog.

So, i just use

```
QTimer::singleShot(50, this, [this](){
    hide(); //hide dialog
});
```

in close handler function. It seems work well.

Comment: 50ms was not enough in my case. I had to use an even bigger timeout (I use 2000ms which is OK for me but probably much lower values are possible as well)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem occurs because "show" and "hide" calls interlace. To verify this, use a semaphore - lock the object until show have finished, and wait on it in hide. Also look at the top-voted answer here for another possible (perhaps better) solution: [connecting signal/slot across different threads between QObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548996/connecting-signal-slot-across-different-threads-between-qobjects)

Comment: Used a QMutex to set a lock in both Show()/Hide() functions to lock/unlock before and after the actions; no success. I've also read through the linked solution and attempted all logical connection types and the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` to connect signals to slots. Be sure that event loop of main thread is not blocked. Also, if your worker thread uses a lot of cpu time - you may call `QThread::yeldCurrentThread()` call.