# time.sleep() crashes program when using while-loop in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt

When I use the function time.sleep() in the terminal, it is no problem.
When I use PyQt and want to use a label, it crashes and/or only shows the last number.

By the way: I want a function, that counts e.g. a year from 2020 to 2030 in various speed, that the user can change and the year should be shown in a label.

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
# timer that counts in the future with various speed // still crashing
def timer(self):
    x=datetime.datetime.now()
    z=x.ctime()
    self.ui.labelDateTime.setText(z)
    var=x.year
    while True:
        if var==2030:
            break
        else:
            var+=1
            y=x.replace(year=var)
            z=y.ctime()
            self.ui.labelDateTime.setText(z)
            time.sleep(0.5)
    print("You are dead")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()` within your for loop to make the Qt's event loop proceed the incoming event (from keyboard or mouse or sleep).

Although calling `QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()` works , I have read in many places on the web that it should be a last resort. Unfortunately none of the sources clearly explain why -- but see for example

- [How to make Qt work when main thread is busy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386043/how-to-make-qt-work-when-main-thread-is-busy)
- [Should I use QCoreApplication::processEvents() or QApplication::processEvents()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150966/should-i-use-qcoreapplicationprocessevents-or-qapplicationprocessevents)
- [How to implement a QThread that runs forever{} with a QWaitCondition but still needs to catch another Slot while doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102040/how-to-implement-a-qthread-that-runs-forever-with-a-qwaitcondition-but-still-n/6102176#6102176)
- http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22967

So it does seem allowed, but in general, it seems to be better design to use `QTimer` or `QThread`.

Comment: " QtTest.QTest.qWait(millisec) " ist the best solution with the best GUI performance for my program ^^